# Удалить из строки последовательность символов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно удалить из строки последовательность символов `ХХХл.pdf`.

```
$str = "Какой-то текст 34л.pdf";
```

Количество цифр не известно, но не более 1000. Прошу помощи с регуляркой.

```
$pattern = '\d+л\.pdf';
$replacement = '';
$origin = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Comment: \d+л\.pdf что вот такое не берет?

Comment: @splash, рубит всю строку

Comment: покажите код, как вы удаляете?

Comment: @splash, обновил свой вопрос

Comment: Разобрался, вот такая получилась /\d+л\.pdf/iD

Comment: да, имеено в этом и ошибка. не успел написать :)

Comment: @splash58, оформите ответом?

Comment: Да что ж там оформлять-то :)

Comment: )) Таких как я масса, которые с регулярками не дружат

Comment: Напишите сами, имеете право, вы же сами и разобрались, я лучше пообедаю :)

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Модификатор `D` в конце вам не нужен, он влияет на поведение `$` в многострочных данных, ни то ни другое вы тут не использыете. Вместо него рекомендую добавить `u` (utf8) потому как у вас тут русские буквы, так на всякий случай